# How to set up PingID 2FA with third party OTP app

Tags: authentication, 2fa

I would like to be able to generate *pingID* 2FA keys from a generic OTP app such as freeOTP for Android, authy for windowsOS or an OTP app of a smartwatch.

The service allows me to enrol 2 devices and at the moment I have a device with the official "pindID"  client.

To enrol the 2nd device the admin page generates a QR and provides a key/string

Updated:
Originally I was using the default QR or the 13 numeric string to enter manually.

But I've discovered that it is possible to generate different ones through selecting "authenticator. Then, this QR is recognized by 3rd party apps and the string is 32digits alphanumeric.

Now the device appears as paired in the pingID/pingOne console.

However,the device generated code is not working on pingID auth prompts.

BTW, there are differences with pingId client:
PingID client requires to log with a 6 pin password and code/token is renewed after seconds

generic OTP apps, don't require app and the code/token is renewed after much more time
3rd party apps tried:
Android: (freeOTP, freeOTP+,Aegis)
WIndowsOS: Authy
Smartwatch one (not android)

pingID=pingidentity from https://www.pingidentity.com

Comment: Updated, now i can paid 3rd party apps but the generated token is not working. This is not an android issue, but someone moved my original question from Superuser, probably because in the text there are android apps.

Comment: We can close the question on Android.SE so that it will be migrated back to SU, but please note that the question will stay closed there. You might need to edit and clarify the question there to avoid misunderstanding. Do you want this question to be closed?